# Create Interceptor class for WSO2 API Manager

Tags: class, wso2, wso2-api-manager, interceptor, api-manager

I am new to WSO2 AM and I would like to create interceptor class for APIs that are published on my company's server on API Manager. The thing is that I need to create a solution for DRM (Digital Rights Management), to do so I need to create the class that intercepts all calls to my APIs and do some control check from the JSON that arrives with the user token and some user's parameters.
Until now I was searching for the answers on google for weeks, but didn't find anything useful. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can write a custom handler for this. Please follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Writing+Custom+Handlers

Answer (score 2):

API request/response interceptors in WSO2 API Manager are called handlers. APIM comes with a set of default handlers for authentication, rate limiting, analytics etc. and you can define your own custom handlers as well. Follow these docs for details.

APIM 2.6.0: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Writing+Custom+Handlers

APIM 3.0.0: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/Learn/APIGateway/Handlers/writing-custom-handlers/